# Pattern Matching with Private Field

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala>   case class ParentPath(private val x: String) {
     |     val value = x.dropWhile(_ == '/')
     | }
```

I can make a `ParentPath`:

```
scala> ParentPath("/foo")
res10: ParentPath = ParentPath(/foo)
```

I can't access its `x` (due to `private`, it appears).

```
scala> res10.
asInstanceOf   canEqual   copy   isInstanceOf   productArity   productElement   productIterator   productPrefix   toString   value
```

I can get its `value`.

```
scala> res10.value
res11: String = foo
```

However, I'd prefer to return its `value` rather than `x` upon a pattern match:

```
scala> res10 match { case ParentPath(x) => x}
res13: String = /foo
```

How can I pattern match with `value` rather than `x`?

```
scala> ParentPath.unapply(res10)
res15: Option[String] = Some(/foo)
```

I tried to override `ParentPath#unapply`, but got a compile-time error:

```
scala>   case class ParentPath(private val x: String) { 
     |     val value = "foo"
     |     override def unapply(p: ParentPath): Option[String] = Some(value)
     |   }
<console>:15: error: method unapply overrides nothing
           override def unapply(p: ParentPath): Option[String] = Some(value)
                        ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unapply` method belongs in the companion object, and you cannot override it for a case class, anyway. For a normal class, this will work. *Or*, if you simply use a differently named object that has an `unapply` method of the same signature.

```
class ParentPath(private val x: String) { 
    val value = "foo"
}

object ParentPath {
    def unapply(p: ParentPath): Option[String] = Some(p.value)
}

scala> new ParentPath("/foo") match { case ParentPath(x) => x }
res1: String = foo
```

Comment: `you cannot override it for a case class, anyway` Oh, so it's `final` then?

Comment: It conflicts with the `unapply` method that the case class companion tries to generate.